# How can i extract Cookie Values from this responses AFTER login succesuful ? (Golang Cookie)

Tags: authentication, go, cookies

This is my code, works well, i can login in the main page and i saw a redirect page, to poertal, with header basic (i beleive worked) .
The header of top menu , shown to me.

But i cannot get all cookies from this successeful request to instruiment apis.
Anyone now what i missing ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "io"
    _ "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    _ "strings"
    "sync"
)

type Jar struct {
    sync.Mutex
    cookies map[string][]*http.Cookie
}

func NewJar() *Jar {
    jar := new(Jar)
    jar.cookies = make(map[string][]*http.Cookie)
    return jar
}

func (jar *Jar) SetCookies(u *url.URL, cookies []*http.Cookie) {
    jar.Lock()
    if _, ok := jar.cookies[u.Host]; ok {
        for _, c := range cookies {
            jar.cookies[u.Host] = append(jar.cookies[u.Host], c)
        }
    } else {
        jar.cookies[u.Host] = cookies
    }
    jar.Unlock()
}

func (jar *Jar) Cookies(u *url.URL) []*http.Cookie {
    return jar.cookies[u.Host]
}

func NewJarClient() *http.Client {
    return &http.Client{
        Jar: NewJar(),
    }
}

func fetch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // create the client
    client := NewJarClient()

    // get the csrf token
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://developer.domain.com.br/pt-BR/sign-in", nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    csrfToken := ""
    if val, ok := doc.Find(`head meta[name="csrf-token-value"]`).Attr("content"); ok {
        csrfToken = val
    }

    // post on the login form.
    resp, _ = client.PostForm("domain.com", url.Values{
        "UserLogin[email]":    {"xxxx"},
        "UserLogin[password]": {"yyyyy"},
        "csrf_token":          {csrfToken},
    })

    cookies := resp.Cookies()
    fmt.Println("try get Cookie")
    for _, c := range cookies {
       
            // Found! Use it!
            fmt.Println(c.Value) // The cookie's value
        
    }
        fmt.Println("end get Cookie")

   
    doc, err = goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // if i stop here then i can see just fine the dashboard where i am redirected after login.
    // but if i continue and request a 3rd page, then i get the login page again,
    // sign that i lose the cookies and i am redirected back

     // html, _ := doc.Html()
     // io.WriteString(w, html)
     // fmt.Print(html)
     // return

    // from this point on, any request will give me the login page once again.
    // i am not sure why since the cookies should be set and sent on all requests
    req, _ = http.NewRequest("GET", "https://developer.domain.com.br/pt-BR/developer/profile", nil)
    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
    doc, err = goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    html, _ := doc.Html()
    io.WriteString(w, html)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", fetch)
    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:49721", nil)
}
```

Extract Cookies After Login succesful

Comment: You post to `domain.com` but then get from `developer.domain.com.br` - check that `Cookies` is actually sending the cookies you expect it is (simplest way is probably to add logging in `Cookies` to output `u.Host` and `jar.cookies[u.Host]`). As it looks like you have probably redacted the urls it's difficult to know if this is the issue but it's a starting point (please edit the question and add your findings).

Comment: i will try. and repost more data and details. tks